Staining new pine T&G, seeking opinions and expertise
Was redirected here from another stack. I am trying to figure out my stain for a new pine T&G vaulted ceiling in a bedroom.
Original plan was to match the oak floor stain which will be Provincial. We were going for a darker, cozier feel for the room.
However, after seeing some of the darker/medium stains on the pine sample pieces they do not look like what I had pictured in my head. Trying to figure out if we should continue with the plan and stain with Provincial or Early American with a satin poly coating, or pivot to something lighter that may work better on the pine.
Anyone have experience or examples of this? Very open to suggestions!
We were originally targeting a stain color similar to that in the following image:


Whatever you do - TEST IT somewhere else.  It's one thing to sand, repair or remove finish on flat or even vertical surfaces.  Altering or removing finish on a ceiling is definitely more difficult.

Thank you! I have done some tests, and they have had surprising results. However, they were only a single coat w/o using a conditioner. Would a second coat make a significant difference in how they appear?

In my experience, pine varies dramatically in its stain absorption from one inch to the next. With no apparent rhyme or reason. Blotchy. Blotchy. Blotchy. Ugh. When you test, do it across a larger area to get a feel for how it will really look.

Hi, welcome to Woodworking! I've drafted a preliminary Answer but before posting it I should see the image you intended to add. Please edit the Question to include it, thanks.

"I have done some tests, and they have had surprising results." Not surprised! Pine doesn't stain how one imagines it should. ".....only a single coat w/o using a conditioner." Note that while "conditioner" and similar products are expressly made to solve blotching issues and reduce uneven absorption of stain, it's rare for the product blurb to mention that they also reduce stain absorption overall. "Would a second coat make a significant difference in how they appear?" If by difference you really mean improvement, then unfortunately very much no. You'd likely think it just looks worse.
